# Define function for extension of abstract class

Tags: scala, abstract-class, type-parameter

I'm having trouble with type mismatches when trying to write a function that takes as input (and output) an object that extends an abstract class.

Here is my abstract class:

```
abstract class Agent {
  type geneType
  var genome: Array[geneType]
}
```

Here is my function:

```
def slice[T <: Agent](parentA: T, parentB: T):(T, T) = {
  val genomeSize = parentA.genome.length

  // Initialize children as identical to parents at first. 
  val childA = parentA
  val childB = parentB

  // the value 'index' is sampled randomly between 0 and 
  // the length of the genome, less 1.  
  // This code omitted for simplicity. 
  val index;
  val pAslice1 = parentA.genome.slice(0, index + 1)
  val pBslice1 = parentB.genome.slice(index + 1, genomeSize)
  val genomeA = Array.concat(pAslice1, pBslice1)
  childA.genome = genomeA

  // And similary for childB. 
  // ...
  // ...

  return (childA, childB)
}
```

I'm receiving an error (I'm running this with sbt, by the way) as follows:

```
[error] ..........  type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[parentA.geneType]
[error]  required: Array[T#geneType]
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, as I'm new to abstract classes, generic type parametrization, and probably other relevant concepts whose names I don't know.

Comment: One thing to notice is that here when you do `parentA.genome.slice(0, index + 1)` the return type is `Array[parentA.type#geneType]` while you expected only `Array[geneType]`. I don't know you why though, probably being `T` a subtype of an abstract class makes it so that the type are bound to the class instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your construction it is well possible that `parentA` and `parentB` are different types, `T` only gives you an upper bound (they must be *at least as specific as T*). Arrays are invariant in their element type, thus you cannot exchange the elements in a sound way here.

A second problem with your code is that you are returning objects of type `T`, but actually you are mutating the input arguments. Either you want mutation, then declare the method's return type `Unit` to make that clear; or create new instances of `T` and make `Agent` immutable. It depends on your performance requirements, but I would always try the immutable variant first, because it is easier to reason about.

Here is mutable variant. Note that because arrays are special objects on the JVM (no type erasure happening), you need to provide a so-called class-tag for them as well:

```
abstract class Agent {
  type geneType
  var genome: Array[geneType]
  implicit def geneTag: reflect.ClassTag[geneType]
}

def slice[A](parentA: Agent { type geneType = A }, 
             parentB: Agent { type geneType = A }): Unit = {
  val genomeSize = parentA.genome.length
  require (parentB.genome.length == genomeSize)
  import parentA.geneTag

  val index    = (math.random * genomeSize + 0.5).toInt
  val (aInit, aTail) = parentA.genome.splitAt(index)
  val (bInit, bTail) = parentB.genome.splitAt(index)
  val genomeA  = Array.concat(aInit, bTail)
  val genomeB  = Array.concat(bInit, aTail)
  parentA.genome = genomeA
  parentB.genome = genomeB
}
```

Here you require that `parentA` and `parentB` share an exactly defined gene-type `A`. You can define a type alias to simplify specifying that type:

```
type AgentT[A] = Agent { type geneType = A }

def slice[A](parentA: AgentT[A], parentB: AgentT[A]): Unit = ...
```

---

To preserve the parents and create new children, the easiest would be to add a copy method to the `Agent` class:

```
abstract class Agent {
  type geneType
  var genome: Array[geneType]
  implicit def geneTag: reflect.ClassTag[geneType]

  def copy(newGenome: Array[geneType]): AgentT[geneType]
}

type AgentT[A] = Agent { type geneType = A }

def slice[A](parentA: AgentT[A], parentB: AgentT[A]): (AgentT[A], AgentT[A]) = {
  val genomeSize = parentA.genome.length
  require (parentB.genome.length == genomeSize)
  import parentA.geneTag

  val index    = (math.random * genomeSize + 0.5).toInt
  val (aInit, aTail) = parentA.genome.splitAt(index)
  val (bInit, bTail) = parentB.genome.splitAt(index)
  val genomeA  = Array.concat(aInit, bTail)
  val genomeB  = Array.concat(bInit, aTail)
  (parentA.copy(genomeA), parentB.copy(genomeB))
}
```

---

If you don't need to squeeze the last bits of performance, you could use an immutable collection such as `Vector` instead of `Array`.

```
case class Agent[A](genome: Vector[A]) {
  def size = genome.size
}

def slice[A](parentA: Agent[A], parentB: Agent[A]): (Agent[A], Agent[A]) = {
  val genomeSize = parentA.size
  require (parentB.size == genomeSize)

  val index    = (math.random * genomeSize + 0.5).toInt
  val (aInit, aTail) = parentA.genome.splitAt(index)
  val (bInit, bTail) = parentB.genome.splitAt(index)
  val genomeA  = aInit ++ bTail
  val genomeB  = bInit ++ aTail
  (parentA.copy(genomeA), parentB.copy(genomeB))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. I think I've got the immutable solution you suggested working (still using Arrays).  How would I go about partially applying this function?

Comment: What do you mean by "partially applying"?

Comment: I mean getting a 'partially applied function' literal kind of like this: 
 
    val slicer = slice(_, _)

Comment: Exactly like you write. Plus the type parameter, e.g. `slice[Int] _`

Comment: one more question. I have chosen to employ the second method you suggested.  If I were to put the abstract class definition and the definition of the "slice" function into different files, where is the most appropriate place to define the type alias? I get an error that the type is not found if I define it in the abstract class. How would I import this type alias into the file defining the slice function?

Comment: Use the [package object](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html). You could also put it in the companion object to `Agent`. Like `object Agent { type Typed[A] = Agent { type geneType = A }}`.

Comment: Cool. That worked out. Btw, is it appropriate to ask a sequence of related small questions in an SO comment thread like I've been doing? If so, I have another question for you.  If not, what is the conventional thing to do? Would I make another post?

Comment: would you mind checking out this post when you get the chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481255/scala-type-alias-vs-extension-of-abstract-class